# Unexpected behaviour by PBC library on windows

Tags: c, mingw-w64, gmp, msys2

I have built gmp and pbc library on windows 64 bit and the configuration is for x86_64-w64-mingw32 using msys2 and mingw-64. Gmp runs fine (checked by running various programs and inspecting the output) but pbc gives abnormal results.
I am trying to run the benchmark tests (benchmark.c in https://github.com/blynn/pbc/tree/master/benchmark) from the official pbc github repository but the program always print "Bug" and exits in the first iteration. 
Although when i tried to download the windows binaries and dll from https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/download.html (the second one in the table), and run the REPORT script. It executes properly. (The script also runs the benchmark.c file from the repo)
What can be the potential problem behind this? Or how can i setup pbc properly on windows 64 bit version?

Comment: Is this question about some code?If it is about some library that you believe has some bug, then report it to the library devs.

Comment: @EugeneSh. This is about a library, yup. I am not sure if that is a bug or not. I doubt that i might have not built the library properly. Hence the question to find out if anyone else have encountered the same issue or not.

Comment: If you're concerned your build could be the issue, it would be prudent to include more information about how you built it. I recommend trying to build the same code on another platform as well (preferably a mainstream GNU/Linux distribution). I see the "BUG!" as well when built current master (fbf45890) using x86_64-w64-mingw32. Unless this turns out to be a trivial misunderstanding, I suggest working with the library author to find out what the "BUG!" here actually means and going from there.